# Chrome does not show Raphael SVG image

Tags: html, image, svg, raphael

I just use following code to add an image to my project,

```
var paper = Raphael("mpdraw_div", 1920, 1080);
var img = paper.image("temp.jpg", 150, 10, 710, 653);
```

When FF, IE8 is showing my image, Chrome is insisting to not show my image in my project, when I create a new page and use the code above, there is no problem.

My project have lots of divs recursively, but I've tried to write mpdraw_div to just after body tag, this is a problem also.

What may be the possible cause of this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I seem to recall that I had to wrangle my page layout a little to make Raphael and Chrome play nicely together.  Do you have your code staged anywhere we could look at it?

Comment: I will try to handle with it. As you mentioned, I decide it is because of Chrome and my html layout. **Thanks a lot.**

Comment: @Zero i think you must look at answer :)

Comment: I'm officially embarrassed =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reailized that it's because of loading an image before raphael is reason to fail.

Solution is to load an image after some ms(I use 100ms) later.

Hope this help to you all.

Comment: did you try to start your script by the `<body onload` event?